# Need help identifying the issue in a moving average

Tags: matlab, moving-average

So I am writing a code in MATLAB to create a moving average. However, every time I run this I get a `NaN` number. I need some help.

```
function [b] = moving_average(data,window,dt)
%Computes moving average 
num_samples = round((window*(1/dt)));
for x = (1:(length(data)-(num_samples-1)));
    mva(x,1) = mean(data(x:(x+num_samples-1)));
end
b = mva;
end
```

This is what I tried entering in: `moving_average(R_emg,.2,1200)`

Comment: Example of input data used would be helppful.

Answer (score 0):

When using window=0.2 and dt=1200, the result of the following code is 0.

```
num_samples = round((window*(1/dt)))
```

Later you select data using:

```
data(x:(x+num_samples-1))
```

Which then results in data(x:(x-1)), which would select no data. Entering an empty matrix in mean results in the NaN you are seeing.

Perhaps you need to switch the window and dt parameters?